# Generic wrapper for System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

I have implemented a simple generic wrapper for MemoryCache class. Its interface looks like ConcurrentDictionary class but I tried to keep it simple. I tried to keep operations atomic, hoping not to break the thread-safety. Is there a mistake about thread-safety? I also want to know if I there are some boxing-unboxing issues I have to think about. Any suggestions about API or some other thing  is appreciated.

```
public interface IMemoryCacheWrapper<T>
{
    string Name { get; }
    long CacheMemoryLimitInBytes { get; }
    long PhysicalMemoryLimit { get; }
    TimeSpan PollingInterval { get; }
    CacheItemPolicy CacheItemPolicy { get; set; }
    void AddOrUpdate(string key, T value);
    bool TryGetValue(string key, out T value);
    bool TryRemove(string key, out T value);
    void Remove(string key);
    bool ContainsKey(string key);
    long Count { get; }
    void Dispose();
    bool IsDisposed { get; }
}


public class MemoryCacheWrapper<T> : IMemoryCacheWrapper<T>
{
    private readonly MemoryCache _memoryCache;
    private CacheItemPolicy _cacheItemPolicy;
    private bool _isDisposed;

    public MemoryCacheWrapper(string name, NameValueCollection config = null)
    {
        _memoryCache = config != null ? new MemoryCache(name, config) : new MemoryCache(name);
        _isDisposed = false;
        CacheItemPolicy = new CacheItemPolicy { SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0) };
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _memoryCache.Name; }
    }

    public long CacheMemoryLimitInBytes
    {
        get { return _memoryCache.CacheMemoryLimit; }
    }

    public long PhysicalMemoryLimit
    {
        get { return _memoryCache.PhysicalMemoryLimit; }
    }

    public TimeSpan PollingInterval
    {
        get { return _memoryCache.PollingInterval; }
    }

    public CacheItemPolicy CacheItemPolicy
    {
        get
        {
            return _cacheItemPolicy;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _cacheItemPolicy = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddOrUpdate(string key, T value)
    {
        _memoryCache.Set(key, value, CacheItemPolicy);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out T value)
    {
        bool result = false;
        value = default(T);

        object item = _memoryCache.Get(key);
        if (item != null)
        {
            value = (T)item;
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public bool TryRemove(string key, out T value)
    {
        bool result = false;
        value = default(T);

        object item = _memoryCache.Remove(key);
        if (item != null)
        {
            result = true;
            value = (T)item;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        _memoryCache.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _memoryCache.Contains(key);
    }

    public long Count
    {
        get { return _memoryCache.GetCount(); }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _memoryCache.Dispose();
        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    public bool IsDisposed
    {
        get { return _isDisposed; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there,came across your class.Planning to use with EF how do you use it?

Comment: @user231465 I didn't like this implementation. I wrote another one using ConcurrentDictionary class. It's called [MemoryCacheT](https://github.com/uhaciogullari/MemoryCacheT). You can take a look at it, sliding cache implementation is a little problematic though.

Comment: Neither your interface nor the implementation actually implement IDisposable, although you have the void Dispose() method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When implementing the Dispose interface it is advisable to use a two stage clean up. So that when you use this not inside a `using clause` the garage collection can also work correctly.

Technically you can get away with it here; but I find it is useful to always use this pattern. Maintenance/Bug fixing then becomes easier as you do not need to start messing with other stuff just update the Dispose method. Another reason is that MS recommends this.

```
    public ~MemoryCacheWrapper()
    {
        // Garbage collection has kicked in tidy up your object.
        Dispose(false);
    }

    // Implement IDisposable.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Dispose has been called clean up your object and members that
        // are disposable.
        Dispose(true);

        // Now Make sure that you don't call the cleanup again via the Finalizer
        // Effectively you are taking over garbage collection so make sure you
        // don't do it again
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        // Only do this once.
        if(!this._isDisposed)
        {
            // If called via IDispose interface then clean up sub-objects.
            // That implement the IDispose interface.
            if(disposing)
            {
                // Dispose managed resources.
                _memoryCache.Dispose();
            }

            // Now clean-up and objects that don't implement dispose.
            // i.e close any file handles 

            // Currently nothing to do.    
        }
        _isDisposed = true;         
    }
```

Comment: Loki is only partly correct. If there is no native resource to clean up in the class, implementing a finalizer is not only redundant, but also wasteful. If the class is designed to be a base class, adding this dispose-plumbing is good, since you never know what a derived class will do. But if the class is *not* designed to be a base class, make it *sealed* and only call Dispose() on your disposable members in the class' Dispose() method - GC.SuppressFinalize isn't needed in that case.

Comment: @JohannGerell: C# is not my favorite language so in the end I will accept your comment as best advice for now but it would be nice to have a reference to some article that backs your opinion. I took this directly from my MS internal training notes (from when I worked at MS). Now my notes are now 3 years old so they could be out wrong or outdated but the "style cop" settings used by our whole division was set to bark and prevent check-in if the above was not adhered to.

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need to implement a Finalizer if the objects you are referencing already does. In other words, you should just implement a Finalizer if your own code is helding reference to non-managed resources. You aren't. The MemoryCache is. So only the Disposing pattern should suffice. MemoryCache himself is the one that has to have the Finalizer implemented. -- remember that implementing a finalizer has the side-effect of making your object only collectible after two runs from the GC, which is bad for memory and performance.